# Can't get the correct string from a JSON response?

Tags: php, json, xcode, swift, nsurl

Why can't I get the correct string from a JSON response?

From the app I do a PHP call and get following JSON data back:

> {"success":1, "session_id":"778a6a66505b785e1130c46227d44641"}

But when I read it in the app the `session_id` is 140407621032752. Why?

Here is a little bit of my code:

```
let responseData:NSString  = NSString(data:urlData!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

NSLog("Response ==> %@", responseData);

let jsonData:NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers ) as! NSDictionary
                        let success:NSInteger = jsonData.valueForKey("success") as! NSInteger
let sessionId:NSString = jsonData.valueForKey("session_id") as! NSString

NSLog("Success: %ld", success)
NSLog("sessionId: %ld", sessionId)
```

And here is output when running it:

> 2016-05-03 14:15:06.826 ran[10974:4371080] Response code: 200
>   2016-05-03 14:15:06.826 ran[10974:4371080] Response ==> {"success":1, "session_id":"778a6a66505b785e1130c46227d44641"}
>   2016-05-03 14:15:06.826 ran[10974:4371080] Success: 1
>   2016-05-03 14:15:06.826 ran[10974:4371080] sessionId: 140407621032752

As you can see `session_id` is coming in correct. But how can I get it?

Answer (score 1):

Your session id is a String, so you have to use the string formatter `%@` for NSLog:

```
NSLog("sessionId: %@", sessionId)
```